# how to declare label in global class (helloworld.h) with cocos2d-x v3.2?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm creating a 2d platform  game with cocos2d-x v3.2 (c++) and i'm using label.

cocos2d-x v3.0 (c++) 
declared like `cocos2d::LabelTTF* currentScore;`

cocos2d-x v2.2.2 (c++) 
declared like  `cocos2d::CCLabelTTF* currentScore;`

cocos2d-x v3.2(c++)
how to declare label in global class(helloworld.h)
i have try like

HelloWorld.h

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::LayerColor

{
public:
  virtual bool init();
cocos2d::LabelTTF* currentScore;   //semantic issue(LabelTTF deprecared)
};

    #endif
```

HelloWorld.cpp

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
currentScore = LabelTTF::create("", "Arial", 40);  //semantic issue(LabelTTF deprecared)

    // position the label on the center of the screen
    currentScore->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                            origin.y + visibleSize.height - currentScore->getContentSize().height));

    // add the label as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(currentScore, 1);

    char buffer[10];
    sprintf(buffer, "%04i",0);
    currentScore->setString(std::string(buffer));
}
```

one more try again

HelloWorld.cpp

```
 bool HelloWorld::init()
    {

    Auto currentScore = LabelTTF::create("", "Arial", 40);
    //position the label on the center of the screen
        currentScore->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                                origin.y + visibleSize.height - currentScore->getContentSize().height));

        // add the label as a child to this layer
        this->addChild(currentScore, 1);
    }
  #endif
```

it working but can't "Auto currentScore;" declared  in global class(HelloWorld.h)

Comment: what's the problem of your first try ? i don't quite get what "global class" mean,maybe your problem is about c++ grammer?

Comment: i'm getting problem in global declaration(in .h class) of LabelTTF in cocos2d-x 3.2 
when i tried, its giving semantic issue(LabelTTF is deprecared) and application crash due to label not found by app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .h file

```
Label *autolabel4;
```

in .cpp

// autolabel4 = Label::create(); can't improve  label size and fount

```
autolabel4 = Label::createWithSystemFont("hello","Arial.ttf",40);
  autolabel4->setString("name isss :");
  autolabel4->setColor(Color3B(23,33,44));
  autolabel4->setPosition(Point(origin.x+ visibleSize.width/2,
                              origin.y + visibleSize.height - 400));
      this->addChild(autolabel4, 1);
```